# Can the Sphinx Search Engine index a folder of xml files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search-engine, sphinx

I have folders that contain xml that I need to index in Sphinx.  I explored the xmlpipe2 driver, and my understanding is that it only reads xml generated from a script, aka, one source.   Is there a way to index a folder of xml files if I don't have the option of putting it a single xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a XMLPipe Script is just a script that outputs XML, which sphinx then ingests.

It doesnt matter WHERE that script, gets the data from that it outputs.

It could get it **from** other the XML files, the script would just walk the folder structure, read all the files, and output XML.

Comment: OK that's what I figured would need to happen.  Thanks!   I take it the output wouldn't need to necessarily be a larger master xml file, but rather a stream of xml documents that get returned to the pipe via stdout?

Comment: Almost, just that it would be a stream of a single XML document. The script needs to output one big XML file, just that it can streams it via stdout